# Opening a responsive side menu when resizing window

Tags: javascript, html, css, menu, responsive

I have been coding a side menu that seems to work fine...but has a bug.

The side menu hides with a media query when window less than 660 px. Then a burger icon appears and the sidebar dissappear.

If you click the burguer, then the menu appears again.

If you click the "X" to close de bar the menu dissappears again.

Until here, all its ok.

Now if you resize to normal size, the sidemenu has completely dissapeared.

I need to open it on resize greater than 660px, but struggling to make it work.

Here is a messy code (I don't have remove some intents to make it work).

```
    var openMenu = function(){
    el = document.getElementsByTagName("aside")[0];
    el.style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("burguer-menu").style.display = "none";
}

var closeMenu = function(){
    el = document.getElementsByTagName("aside")[0];
    el.style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("burguer-menu").style.display = "inline";
}

var openMenuOnResize = function(){
    const mq = window.matchMedia("(min-width: 660px)");
    if (mq.matches) {
        openMenu;
    }
}

document.getElementById("burguer-menu").addEventListener("click", openMenu);
document.getElementById("aside-logo-mb").addEventListener("click", closeMenu);
//window.addEventListener('resize', openMenuOnResize);

/*Resize Window */
 if (matchMedia) {
    const mq = window.matchMedia("(min-width: 660px)");
    mq.addListener(WidthChange);
    WidthChange(mq);
    }

 //    media query change
     function WidthChange(mq) {
    if (mq.matches) { openMenu;
     // window width is at least 660px
    } else {
      window width is less than 660px
     }

    }
```

Here is a [codepen](https://codepen.io/coderlog/pen/wQdqGJ) with the full code.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var openMenu = function(){
    el = document.getElementsByTagName("aside")[0];
    el.style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("burguer-menu").style.display = "none";
}

var closeMenu = function(){
    el = document.getElementsByTagName("aside")[0];
    el.style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("burguer-menu").style.display = "inline";
}

var openMenuOnResize = function(){
    const mq = window.matchMedia("(min-width: 660px)");
    if (mq.matches) {
        openMenu;
    }
}

document.getElementById("burguer-menu").addEventListener("click", openMenu);
document.getElementById("aside-logo-mb").addEventListener("click", closeMenu);
window.addEventListener('resize', openMenuOnResize);

/*Resize Window */
 if (matchMedia) {
    const mq = window.matchMedia("(min-width: 660px)");
    mq.addListener(WidthChange);
    WidthChange(mq);
    }
    
 //    media query change
     function WidthChange(mq) {
    if (mq.matches) { openMenu;
     // window width is at least 660px
  document.getElementById('sidemenu').style.display='block'
  
  
    } else {
     // window width is less than 660px
  document.getElementById('sidemenu').style.display='none';
  var btn=document.getElementById('burguer-menu');
  if(isHidden(btn)){
   btn.style.display='inline';
   }
     }
    
    }
function isHidden(el) {
    var style = window.getComputedStyle(el);
    return (style.display === 'none')
}
```

```css
body {
    display: flex;
    min-height: 100vh;
    flex-direction: row;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
}


/* NAV SECTION */
aside {
    display:inline;
    flex: 1;
    background-color: #1a2b42;
    min-width:280px;
    /* top:0;
    bottom:0;
    width: 20%;
    height: 100%; */
}

.aside-logo {
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    color: white;
    font-size: 2rem;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 100%;
}

.aside-logo p {
    font-size: 12px;
}
#aside-logo-mb {
    display: none;
}

.aside-logo a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    font-size: 3rem;
}

aside hr {
    border-color: #4c5267;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
.menu-link {
    color:#98A4CE;
    padding:20px 3px 20px 20px;
    display:block;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.menu-link:hover{
    color: white;
    border-left:solid 3px #363a51;
    background-color:#363a51;
    padding:20px 30px 20px 40px;
    display:block;

}

.menu-link:active {
    color: #67f494;
    border-left:solid 3px #67f494;
    background-color:#363a51;
    padding:20px 30px 20px 17px;
    display:block;
}

.active-menu-link {
    color: #67f494;
    border-left:solid 3px #67f494;
    background-color:#363a51;
    padding:20px 30px 20px 17px;
    display:block;
}


.far {
    color:#67f494;
    padding-right:15px;
}

.fas {
    color:#67f494;
    padding-right:15px;
}


/* MAIN SECTION */

main {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex: 5;
    background-color:#98A4CE;
}

/*HEADER SECTION*/

header {
    display: flex;
    min-height: 50px;
    background-color: white;
}

.top-nav_right {
    display:flex;
    flex:1;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    margin-right: 30px;
}

.top-nav_left {
    display:none;
    flex: 1;
    flex-direction: row;
}

.top-nav_right-sm {
    display: none;
}

#burguer-menu {
    color:#67f494;
    padding-right:15px;

}

.content{
    flex: 4;
}

footer {
    display: flex;
    min-height: 50px;
    background-color:#4C5267;
}

footer p {
    padding: 0 0 0 30px;
    color:#98A4CE;
}


@media(max-width:660px) {
    aside {
        display:none;
    }
    .aside-logo{
        display:none;
    }

    #aside-logo-mb{
        display: block;
    }

    header{background-color:#1a2b42;}

    .top-nav_left {
        display:flex;
        flex: 1;
        flex-direction: row;
        color: white;
        padding: 0 0 0 20px;
    }

    .top-nav_right-sm {
        display: flex;
    }
    .top-nav_right {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.5.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-B4dIYHKNBt8Bc12p+WXckhzcICo0wtJAoU8YZTY5qE0Id1GSseTk6S+L3BlXeVIU" crossorigin="anonymous">
<aside id="sidemenu">
        <div class="aside-logo" id="aside-logo">
            LOGO
        <p>Your slogan </p>
        
        </div>
        <div class="aside-logo" id="aside-logo-mb">
         <a href="#">&times</a>    
        </div>
        <hr>
        <a href="#" class="active-menu-link"><i class="fas fa-home"></i> Home</a>
        <a href="#" class="menu-link"><i class="far fa-address-book"></i> Item 1</a>
        <a href="#" class="menu-link"><i class="far fa-calendar-alt"></i> Item 2</a>
        <a href="#" class="menu-link"><i class="fas fa-users"></i> Item 3</a>
        <a href="#" class="menu-link"><i class="far fa-check-square"></i> Item 4</a>
        <a href="#" class="menu-link"><i class="far fa-map"></i> Item 5</a>
        <a href="#" class="menu-link"><i class="fas fa-expand"></i> Item 6</a>
        <a href="#" class="menu-link"><i class="fas fa-feather-alt"></i>Item 8</a>
    
</aside>
<main>
    <header>
        <div class="top-nav_left">
            <p>LOGO</p>
        </div>
        <div class="top-nav_right">
                <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-user-circle"></i>Profile</a>
                <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-cog"></i>Settings</a>
        </div>
        <div class="top-nav_right-sm">
                <a href="#" id="burguer-menu" onclick="openMenu"><i class="fas fa-bars"></i></a>
        </div>
    </header>
    <div class="content">

    </div>
    <footer>
        <p>Copyright 2018</p>
        <p>Terms & Conditions</p>

    </footer>


</main>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var openMenu = function(){
    el = document.getElementsByTagName("aside")[0];
    el.style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("burguer-menu").style.display = "none";
}

var closeMenu = function(){
    el = document.getElementsByTagName("aside")[0];
    el.style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("burguer-menu").style.display = "inline";
}

var openMenuOnResize = function(){
    const mq = window.matchMedia("(min-width: 660px)");
    if (mq.matches) {
        openMenu;
    }
}

document.getElementById("burguer-menu").addEventListener("click", openMenu);
document.getElementById("aside-logo-mb").addEventListener("click", closeMenu);
//window.addEventListener('resize', openMenuOnResize);

/*Resize Window */
 if (matchMedia) {
    const mq = window.matchMedia("(min-width: 660px)");
    mq.addListener(WidthChange);
    WidthChange(mq);
    }
    
 //    media query change
     function WidthChange(mq) {
    if (mq.matches) { openMenu;
     // window width is at least 660px
    }
    else {
    }
    
    }
```

```css
/* 
COLOR PALETTE
light green #67f494  (103,244,148)
green #5cc59e     (92,197,158)
greyBlue #385D8E
lightest gray #98A4CE
light gray #4C5267
gray #4c5267     (76,82,103)
middle grey #363a51     (54,58,81)
dark grey #1a2b42     (26,43,66)

FONTS
font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
*/

body {
    display: flex;
    min-height: 100vh;
    flex-direction: row;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
}


/* NAV SECTION */
aside {
    display:inline;
    flex: 1;
    background-color: #1a2b42;
    min-width:280px;
    /* top:0;
    bottom:0;
    width: 20%;
    height: 100%; */
}

.aside-logo {
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    color: white;
    font-size: 2rem;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 100%;
}

.aside-logo p {
    font-size: 12px;
}
#aside-logo-mb {
    display: none;
}

.aside-logo a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    font-size: 3rem;
}

aside hr {
    border-color: #4c5267;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
.menu-link {
    color:#98A4CE;
    padding:20px 3px 20px 20px;
    display:block;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.menu-link:hover{
    color: white;
    border-left:solid 3px #363a51;
    background-color:#363a51;
    padding:20px 30px 20px 40px;
    display:block;

}

.menu-link:active {
    color: #67f494;
    border-left:solid 3px #67f494;
    background-color:#363a51;
    padding:20px 30px 20px 17px;
    display:block;
}

.active-menu-link {
    color: #67f494;
    border-left:solid 3px #67f494;
    background-color:#363a51;
    padding:20px 30px 20px 17px;
    display:block;
}


.far {
    color:#67f494;
    padding-right:15px;
}

.fas {
    color:#67f494;
    padding-right:15px;
}


/* MAIN SECTION */

main {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex: 5;
    background-color:#98A4CE;
}

/*HEADER SECTION*/

header {
    display: flex;
    min-height: 50px;
    background-color: white;
}

.top-nav_right {
    display:flex;
    flex:1;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    margin-right: 30px;
}

.top-nav_left {
    display:none;
    flex: 1;
    flex-direction: row;
}

.top-nav_right-sm {
    display: none;
}

#burguer-menu {
    color:#67f494;
    padding-right:15px;

}

.content{
    flex: 4;
}

footer {
    display: flex;
    min-height: 50px;
    background-color:#4C5267;
}

footer p {
    padding: 0 0 0 30px;
    color:#98A4CE;
}


@media(max-width:660px) {
    aside {
        display:none;
    }
    .aside-logo{
        display:none;
    }

    #aside-logo-mb{
        display: block;
    }

    header{background-color:#1a2b42;}

    .top-nav_left {
        display:flex;
        flex: 1;
        flex-direction: row;
        color: white;
        padding: 0 0 0 20px;
    }

    .top-nav_right-sm {
        display: flex;
    }
    .top-nav_right {
        display: none;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 660px) {
  aside {
      display: inline !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.5.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-B4dIYHKNBt8Bc12p+WXckhzcICo0wtJAoU8YZTY5qE0Id1GSseTk6S+L3BlXeVIU" crossorigin="anonymous">
<aside>
        <div class="aside-logo" id="aside-logo">
            LOGO
        <p>Your slogan </p>
        
        </div>
        <div class="aside-logo" id="aside-logo-mb">
         <a href="#">&times</a>    
        </div>
        <hr>
        <a href="#" class="active-menu-link"><i class="fas fa-home"></i> Home</a>
        <a href="#" class="menu-link"><i class="far fa-address-book"></i> Item 1</a>
        <a href="#" class="menu-link"><i class="far fa-calendar-alt"></i> Item 2</a>
        <a href="#" class="menu-link"><i class="fas fa-users"></i> Item 3</a>
        <a href="#" class="menu-link"><i class="far fa-check-square"></i> Item 4</a>
        <a href="#" class="menu-link"><i class="far fa-map"></i> Item 5</a>
        <a href="#" class="menu-link"><i class="fas fa-expand"></i> Item 6</a>
        <a href="#" class="menu-link"><i class="fas fa-feather-alt"></i>Item 8</a>
    
</aside>
<main>
    <header>
        <div class="top-nav_left">
            <p>LOGO</p>
        </div>
        <div class="top-nav_right">
                <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-user-circle"></i>Profile</a>
                <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-cog"></i>Settings</a>
        </div>
        <div class="top-nav_right-sm">
                <a href="#" id="burguer-menu" onclick="openMenu"><i class="fas fa-bars"></i></a>
        </div>
    </header>
    <div class="content">

    </div>
    <footer>
        <p>Copyright 2018</p>
        <p>Terms & Conditions</p>

    </footer>


</main>
```